# python encryption and decryption query

Tags: python, encryption

So I am in a beginner python class. I am also in intermediate C++, but this assignment is throwing me for a loop.
Here are the two parts:
Encryption:

```
    # encrypt.py - ENCODE MESSAGE AND WRITE TO FILE
#
# initialize a cipher list to store the numeric value of each character
# input a string of text to encrypt
#
# for each character in the string:
# convert the character to its unicode value
# encode the unicode value into an integer with an encryption formula
# convert the encoded integer to a string
# append the encoded string to the cipher list
#
# for debugging purposes, print the cipher list - make sure data is correct
#
# open an output file to store the encrypted message
# write (print) the cipher list to the file
# close the file
def main():
    cipher = []
    #initialize string message
    message=input('Please enter your message for encryption: ')

    #loops through string message and encrypts 
    for ch in message:
        x = ord(ch)
        x = (2*x)-3
        x = chr(x)
        cipher.append(x)
    #Print cipher from prompt
    print("Your code message is: ",cipher)
    #open file for writing
    outFile = open("Encryptedmessage.txt","w")
    print(cipher, file=outFile)
main()

This program works fine. The decryption program is as follows:

    # decrypt.py - DECODE MESSAGE FROM FILE AND DISPLAY
#
# initialize a message list to contain the decoded message
# open the input file containing the encrypted message
# read the line containing the message from the file into a string
# split the string into a cipher list of individual strings
#
# for each string in the cipher list:
# convert the string to an integer
# decode the integer into its unicode value using the decryption formula
# convert the unicode value to its corresponding character
# append the character to the message list
#
# print the message list
# close the file

def main():
    deCipher=[]

    infile = open("Encryptedmessage.txt","r")
    with open('Encryptedmessage.txt') as f:
        lines=f.readlines()
    secMess=str.split

    for ch in infile:
        y=ord(ch)
        y=(y//2)+3
        y=chr(y)
        deCipher.append(y)
        print(deCipher)



main()
```

I get the following error when I try to run decrypt.py:

```
>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/Python34/decrypt.py", line 34, in <module>
    main()
  File "G:/Python34/decrypt.py", line 26, in main
    y=ord(ch)
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 59 found
>>>
```

I have been trying to find some direction in this to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I had tried that also...and I get: <code>>>> 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "G:/Python34/decrypt.py", line 34, in <module>
        main()
      File "G:/Python34/decrypt.py", line 25, in main
       for ch in secMess:
    TypeError: 'method_descriptor' object is not iterable
>>><code>

Comment: I don't really understand your directions...print the individual characters?      Like <code> print(ch) <code>?

Answer (score 0):

You have one mistake in your encrypt; change the last line to:

```
print(''.join(cipher), file=outFile)
```

Then, this will work for decryption:

```
def main():
    deCipher=[]

    infile = open("Encryptedmessage.txt","r")
    with open('Encryptedmessage.txt') as f:
        lines=f.readlines()
    secMess=lines[0].rstrip()

    for ch in secMess:
        y=ord(ch)
        y=(y+3)//2
        y=chr(y)
        deCipher.append(y)
    print(''.join(deCipher))
main()
```

For one thing, you have the wrong decrypt formula. For another, you are iterating on a wrong thing (`infile`), and your `secMess` is also not what you thought it should be.

Comment: Thank you. I was told that append and join were somewhat the same thing, but I can see that isn't exactly true. I'm not completely sure if my professor will accept this as I don't believe he has covered it all yet. I will examine what you put on here and try to learn from it. Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, that is for the best. About your questions, `join` takes a list and smushes it together into a string; `append` adds a new element to the list. (`append` is "put another item into the cart" and `join` is "cook dinner", so to say). You need `rstrip` because a line would have a newline character at the end.